# Add a file extension in R to multiple files

Tags: r

I would like to add the ".txt" file extension to multiple files with no current extension. I can create a vector that contains the file paths using the code below, but I don't know how to add the ".txt" file extension:

```
startingDir <-"/myDirectory"
filez<-list.files(startingDir)
head(filez)
[1] "/myDirectory/File1"
[2] "/myDirectory/File2"
[3] "/myDirectory/File3"
```

Comment: `file.rename(filez, <whichever answer below>)`

Comment: When I run: 
`startingDir <- "/myDirectory"
filez<-list.files(startingDir)
newNames <- paste0(filez,".txt")
file.rename(filez, newNames)`
I get this:
`file.rename(filez, newNames)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`
The file names/extensions don't seem to be changed when I look at the files in my Windows folder.

Answer (score 3):

try `paste(filez ,".txt", sep="")` 
you should be append ".txt" to all elements in the list

Comment: Or just `paste0(filez, ".txt")`

Comment: The commands change the file names in the list, but not the actual file names (file names I can view in the Windows folder).

Answer (score 3):

If you already know the files have no extension and just need to add them, `sub` would be fine.

```
f <- c('/myDirectory/File1', '/myDirectory/File2', '/myDirectory/File3')
f <- sub('$', '.txt', f)
# [1] "/myDirectory/File1.txt" "/myDirectory/File2.txt" "/myDirectory/File3.txt"
```

But if you need to perform a sanity check, I would propose something like the following. This will check which files actually have an extension and if they don't then `.txt` will be appended to those certain files.

```
f <- c('/myDirectory/File1', '/myDirectory/File2', '/myDirectory/File3.csv')
f <- ifelse(!grepl('\\.[^.]+$', f), paste0(f, '.txt'), f)
# [1] "/myDirectory/File1.txt" "/myDirectory/File2.txt" "/myDirectory/File3.csv"
```

Comment: When I run:
`f <- c('/myDirectory/file1','/myDirectory/file2','/myDirectory/file3')
f <- sub('$', '.txt', f)`

I get:
`> f
[1] "/myDirectory/file1.txt"
[2] "/myDirectory/file2.txt"     
[3] "/myDirectory/file3.txt"`  However, when I look at the files in my Windows folder, the names and extensions haven't changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sprintf`

```
x <- c("/myDirectory/File1", "/myDirectory/File2", "/myDirectory/File3")
sprintf("%s.txt", x)
# [1] "/myDirectory/File1.txt" "/myDirectory/File2.txt" "/myDirectory/File3.txt"
```

Comment: 'sprintf' does not appear to change the file name nor the extension when I view the files in my Windows folder.